# How to verify search results data on a web page

Tags: gui

- I was asked a question in an Interview, how will I verify the search results on the page if they are correct or not? For example on the Sky scanner website, I have searched flights from one destination to another. How can I verify those results are correct? My answer was that I will compare the results total with the network console API.
- Second question if the filter is applied on the server side, how can I verify it on the client side?

Comment: Welcome to the community! FYI, multiple questions should be asked in multiple posts, not in 1 post. Can you put your second question in a new post?

Comment: sure! I will post the second question in a seperate post.

Answer (score -1):

It will depend on what you mean by "correct".

Regarding Capability quality criteria, you have to investigate how it ranks the flight data points under different conditions.

Also you can investigate Usabilty, Charisma, Performance, Reliability, Scalability, etc.

[image: ![enter image description here]
(Image: [Heuristic Test Strategy Model](http://thatsabug.com/blog/the-heuristic_testing_strategy_model_mindmap_/))

Once you determine which Quality Criteria you want to investigate,
you can then research reliable Oracles, which will help you to interpret what you see in your product.

[image]

E.g., if you want to understand the Capability of your API to return the flights of a given airport in a given day, you can look into similar products (Google Flights, flight companies sites) and compare with what your product gives. If a flight is seeing in Google Flights but not in your product, it may be a problem.

Comment: That was very detailed answer, Thanks. I might have missed the important point here about the correct data. By correct means, the data fetched by the backend APIs and the data displayed on the Frontend. How can I verify that the Data displayed on client level matches the data fetched from the server side.

Comment: I've amended the answer with a section about Oracles. Let me know if it looks good to you.